jetpack compose navigation animation issues
why is there a fade animation during navigation since im using normal navigation. the code is attached below:
MainActivity:
setContent {
    GrooveShareTheme {
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = "auth"
        ) {
            navigation(
                startDestination = "signup",
                route = "auth"
            ) {
                composable("signup") { SignUpScreen(navController, spotifyAuthViewModel) }
                composable("login") { LogInScreen(navController) }
                composable("password_reset") { PasswordResetScreen(navController) }
            }
            navigation(
                startDestination = "home",
                route = "main"
            ) {
                composable("home") { HomeScreen(navController) }
                composable("friends") { FriendsScreen(navController) }
                composable("add") { AddScreen(navController, currentlyPlayingTrack) }
                composable("notifications") { NotificationsScreen(navController) }
                composable("profile") { ProfileScreen(navController, spotifyUserViewModel) }
            }
        }
    }
}

SignUp Screen:
ClickableText(
            text = text,
            onClick = { offset ->
                text.getStringAnnotations(tag = "LogIn", start = offset, end = offset)
                    .firstOrNull()?.let {
                        navController.navigate("login") {
                            popUpTo("auth") {
                                inclusive = true
                            }
                        }
                    }
            },
            style = TextStyle(
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.white),
                fontSize = 16.sp,
                fontFamily = fontFamily,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            )
        )

im adding this text here cause stackoverflow wont let me post my question cause its mostly code but yh hyd how was your day
example
